# libsndfile.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

```
libsndfile.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0-static/ruby-audio-1.6.1/rubyaudio_ext.so (LoadError)
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/ruby-audio-1.6.1/lib/ruby-audio.rb:6:in `require'
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/ruby-audio-1.6.1/lib/ruby-audio.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/ruby-audio-1.6.1/lib/ruby-audio.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/json-waveform-0.2.1/lib/json-waveform.rb:3:in `require'
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/json-waveform-0.2.1/lib/json-waveform.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
  /var/app/current/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
  /var/app/current/config/environment.rb:2:in `require'
  /var/app/current/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
  config.ru:3:in `require'
  config.ru:3:in `block in <main>
```

But when i check as

```
"ll  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0-static/ruby-audio-1.6.1/"
```

File is present there in redhat aws server.

How can I fix this issue ? 
Thanks

Comment: try `apt-get install libsndfile1-dev` and then retry

Comment: Can you paste your passenger.conf file above?

Comment: it is aws  redhat machine.  By this way if i try with "yum install libsndfile1-dev"  give me following message "No package libsndfile1-devel available".
I have installed it manually from "http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/files/libsndfile-1.0.27.tar.gz"

Comment: @error above output is from passenger.log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ldconfig -p | grep libsndfile.so
```

If this doesn't find the file then find where your libsndfile-1.0.27 is.

Add the directory of the path to libsendfile-1.0.27 to a file in /etc/ld.so.conf.d.

After adding the file to /etc/ld.conf.d run `ldconfig`

Comment: Perfect answer! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can manually add the missing .so file with an apt-get package

> apt-get install libsndfile1

I encountered this issue when running the 'soundfile' python library in a Docker container. Adding the apt-get command to my Dockerfile fixed the issue.